# Trouble with if…else line in R

Tags: r

I am stuck with the `if`…`else` in R:

```
Version <- function(a,b,data) {

  version1=a*b
  version2=a+b
  version3=a-b

  if (data==version1) {

    a=(a*b) 
    return(a)

  } else if (data==version2){

    y=(a+b)
    return(y)

  } else {

    (data==version3) 
    z=(a-b)
    return(z)

  }

}
```

The problem is : `Error in Version(1, 2, version2) : object 'version2'` not found

EDIT:

I apologize for not clarifyng my request.

I am trying to do the task in the else/if statemant.

I should be able to ask for a "version" in the function, but can choose what version I would want to use ( version1,version2 or version3). If I type in version5 or something completely different, it should stop the exectuion and I should get a error message saying so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `switch`:

```
Version <- function(a,b,test){
  switch (tolower(test),
          "version1" = a*b,
          "version2" = a+b,
          "version3" = a-b,
          "unknown selector")
}

Version(2, 3, "Version1")  
#[1] 6

Version(2, 3, "verSion2") 
#[1] 5

Version(2, 3, "Version5")
#[1] "unknown selector"
```

Comment: I think I am such a beginner that if confuses me what you did there. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Yes, I was not aware that these two solutions are different. I am kinda confused with these If..Else statements. How would the line look with If..Else?

Switch is basicilly a fast If..Else?

And is tolower for every letter?

Comment: `tolower` changes all letters in a string to lower case. You use `switch` if you want to select one option of several. You can do the same with nested `if`/`else`, but that's 1) bad style and 2) more work. E.g., you could do `if (tolower(test) == "version1") a*b else {if (tolower(test) == "version2") a+b else {...`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without `switch` and `ifelse`:

```
Version <- function(a, b, test)
  match.fun(c("*", "+", "-")[match(test, c("version1", "version2", "version3"))])(a, b)

Version(3, 4, "version1")
# [1] 12
Version(3, 4, "version2")
# [1] 7
Version(3, 4, "version3")
# [1] -1
```

Comment: +1, but if they have trouble understanding `switch`, they won't understand this.